# Visual Studio 2017 Raspberry Pi Raspbian (Linux) Connection/Build Failure

Tags: visual-studio, ssh, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I'm getting error while trying to connect to Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ using Cross Platform Connection Manager in Visual Studio 2017.

System Specifications-
Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
Version 15.7.4

I'm facing issues while trying to Connect to Raspberry Pi.It gives error while Downloading and updating headers for IntelliSense.

[image: Error snapshot when updating headers]

I have Zip package installed in Raspberry Pi.

I have enabled WSL on my PC.

I had changed the SSH port number in Raspberry Pi to 24 after reading articles, with WSL enabled may cause port number conflict.

The contents of `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\vslinux_header_update_log.txt`

```
liblinux.ExceptionBase: Failed to archive sysroot, command used: 'zip -r /var/tmp/sysroot_58cf76b6-9a42-4d28-b56f-eb7e4a8d7152.zip '.
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysrootArchive()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.DownloadSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateLocalSysroot()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Linux.Package.Dialogs.HeaderUpdateDialog.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<DownloadUpdate>b__0(Object _)

liblinux.ExceptionBase: Failed to archive sysroot, command used: 'zip -r /var/tmp/sysroot_bc0c8b61-9015-449c-9d73-c50556d78085.zip '.
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysrootArchive()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.DownloadSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateLocalSysroot()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Linux.Package.Dialogs.HeaderUpdateDialog.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<DownloadUpdate>b__0(Object _)

liblinux.ExceptionBase: Failed to archive sysroot, command used: 'zip -r /var/tmp/sysroot_5edacd19-9824-4878-b754-9593eda2c34c.zip '.
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysrootArchive()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.DownloadSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateLocalSysroot()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Linux.Package.Dialogs.HeaderUpdateDialog.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<DownloadUpdate>b__0(Object _)

liblinux.ExceptionBase: Failed to archive sysroot, command used: 'zip -r /var/tmp/sysroot_c82fda29-58b6-401a-a922-2f2ba3e5aaee.zip '.
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysrootArchive()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.DownloadSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateLocalSysroot()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Linux.Package.Dialogs.HeaderUpdateDialog.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<DownloadUpdate>b__0(Object _)

liblinux.ExceptionBase: Failed to archive sysroot, command used: 'zip -r /var/tmp/sysroot_d5a9b84e-02ca-4953-bb3a-2e9e2807fc35.zip '.
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysrootArchive()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.DownloadSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateLocalSysroot()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Linux.Package.Dialogs.HeaderUpdateDialog.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<DownloadUpdate>b__0(Object _)

liblinux.ExceptionBase: Failed to archive sysroot, command used: 'zip -r /var/tmp/sysroot_6beaebe0-61c8-4823-ad51-7334d595214c.zip /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include /usr/local/include /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include-fixed /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/include /usr/include/c++/4.9 /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9/. /usr/include/c++/4.9/backward'.
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysrootArchive()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.DownloadSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateLocalSysroot()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Linux.Package.Dialogs.HeaderUpdateDialog.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<DownloadUpdate>b__0(Object _)

liblinux.ExceptionBase: Failed to archive sysroot, command used: 'zip -r /var/tmp/sysroot_35e760b1-b975-4667-b92a-7d9d37a91a99.zip /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include /usr/local/include /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include-fixed /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/include /usr/include/c++/4.9 /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9/. /usr/include/c++/4.9/backward'.
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysrootArchive()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.DownloadSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateLocalSysroot()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Linux.Package.Dialogs.HeaderUpdateDialog.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<DownloadUpdate>b__0(Object _)

liblinux.ExceptionBase: Failed to archive sysroot, command used: 'zip -r /var/tmp/sysroot_de18236a-d534-4d44-9354-f2b37e2103e2.zip '.
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysrootArchive()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.DownloadSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateLocalSysroot()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Linux.Package.Dialogs.HeaderUpdateDialog.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<DownloadUpdate>b__0(Object _)

liblinux.ExceptionBase: Failed to archive sysroot, command used: 'zip -r /var/tmp/sysroot_2ecb6a6a-ad6d-4a7b-99fd-dab0178e6e9f.zip '.
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysrootArchive()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.DownloadSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateSysroot()
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.CreateLocalSysroot()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Linux.Package.Dialogs.HeaderUpdateDialog.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<DownloadUpdate>b__0(Object _)
```

The program build fails when I try to build a program in g++-8.1.0 on Raspberry Pi 3.
I have successfully build g++-8.1.0 and compiled a c++17 program on it (native build).

```
g++ exited with code 1, please see the Output Window - Build output for more details (NOTE: the build output verbosity might need to be changed in Tools Options to see more information in the Output Window). ConsoleApplication6 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets 310
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be a comment but I can't post comments with rep below 50...

The errors from your log file are the same as those listed here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/274

These are errors related to zip not being installed (or found) on the Raspberry Pi.  I realized you mentioned that you have a Zip package installed on the Pi.  Is it possibly gzip?

The link specifies that only zip (and specifically not gzip) is currently supported.  I'd try installing (or reinstalling) zip from the apt-get repository to, hopefully, ensure it is installed in the place Visual Studio is looking for it.  Good luck.